# Load website in first Iframe and its front end code in second Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just for the sake of learning Im asking this question.
I'm using 2 iframes 
lets suppose I load a random website in Iframe1 Is it possible that its front end code is displayed in the 2nd Iframe dynamically/automatically.
Im talking about the code you see once you press CTRL+U on any webpage.
Please help

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Loading any sites to iFrame**

You can do it but **not for all** sites, cause some sites like google and stackoverflow blocks their loading to frames.

**Getting any site content**

You can`t do it, you can do it only if you iframe domain are the same as your site domain (Here is the description of policy [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)).

**But**

You can do some hacks, here is 
[solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Also here is fiddle that illustrate same origin policy exception. Use console to see it.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7eqeqq2y/1/)

Fiddle code

```
<iframe name="site_frame" id="site_frame" src="http://iherb.com">
</iframe>

<iframe id="code_frame">
    <textarea id="code"></textarea>
</iframe>

document.getElementById('site_frame').onload = function () {    
    console.log("Frame loaded!");
    var siteFrameDoc = getIFrameDocument(document.getElementById('site_frame')),        
        siteFrameHtml = siteFrameDoc.getElementByTagName('html'); 
        wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.appendChild(siteFrameHtml.cloneNode(true));


    var codeFrameDoc = getIFrameDocument(document.getElementById('code_frame'));
    var textarea = codeFrameDoc.getElementById("code");
    console.log(textarea);

    textarea.value = wrapper.innerHtml; 
};

function getIFrameDocument(iframe) {      
    return iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;     
}
```